# Python Regular Expression - match , compare and decide

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I have a dictionary which has the different Ip's as Key and its  ping result as the Value.  i want to proceed with my script only when the ping results passes a certain criteria

Assuming the following as the ping result (dictionary Value):

```
10 packets transmitted, 10 packets received, 0.00% packet loss
```

I have created a regular expression and have extracted each of the values as below:

```
match = re.search(r'(\d+\s* packet\w* transmitted), (\d+\s* packet\w* received), (\d+\.\d+ packet loss)',str,re.M|re.I)

>>> match.group(3)
'10.00% packet loss'
```

I have extracted the values..

Now  i want to write a regular expression with a criteria , through which i will ask the script to proceed with execution only if the packet loss percentage is less than 5 % for each Ip;s on my dictionary.

I can think of again taking the numbers from the packet loss and then comparing but was just wondering if there is a better way to do that?

if any ideas, kindly share ..

Comment: Is this a typo `\d+ *  <-- Nested quantifier` ?

Comment: oops sorry it was a typo.

Comment: @sln How is that a nested quantifier? I see `one or more digits followed by zero or more spaces`. Or did you have a typo as well ;)

Comment: @KennethK. - He had a typo before `\d+*`. Think he fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a regex:

```
s = "10 packets transmitted, 10 packets received, 0.00% packet loss"
trans,recv,loss = s.split(",")

print(trans,recv,loss)
('10 packets transmitted', ' 10 packets received', ' 0.00% packet loss')
print(float(loss.split("%")[0] > 5))
False
```

If you have a dict use `all` to check if every value is > 5 percent

Answer (score 2):

You can match just the section of interest, and only for numbers less than 5% with a regular expression:

```
match = re.search(r' +[0-4]\.\d+% packet loss', str, re.M | re.I)
if match:
    do_stuff_with_match()
```

However, please note that regular expressions are much slower than numerical comparison, so you may still wish to use the results of the previous parsing.

Comment: The regex does not do numerical comparison, so it can't be slower. In fact since it has to be parsed anyway, a no match on `[0-4]` is all that should be needed.

Comment: May I know the significance of the + here in the regex? because i could match with this itself.                                      match = re.search(r'[0-5]\.\d+% packet loss',str,re.M|re.I)           >>> match
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02ADE608>
>>>

Comment: The `[space]+` is matching the leading spaces. But you are correct, you can get by without it. If you were using [match](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.match) OTH, you would need that bit; but then your regex would need to be different anyway.

Comment: @sln: Regular expression parsing is much slower than a simple numerical comparison. Try it out with `timeit`. In the case here, the numerical parsing is already done, so using those results is more efficient than using a second regex. In general, it's best to use regex for parsing, and then deal with the parsed results later, rather than re-parsing.

Comment: `use regex for parsing, and then deal with the parsed results later, rather than re-parsing` - Yeah, who said anything about re-parsing? There is no need to reparse anything nor use a float conversion (especially in a Boolean expression). A simple `([^,]+),([^,]+),(\s*(?:(0*[0-4])|\d+)\.\d+%[^,]+)` match && group 4 is not NULL is all that's needed. It's simple validation.